# constexpr Sin Function C++ 14

Tags: c++, mathematics, c++14, template-meta-programming

I have written a `constexpr` sin function using c++14 and would like to know what I can do to improve it. I am trying to balance code clarity/maintainability with performance. My goal was to have every part of the algorithm that does not depend on a run-time parameter be evaluated at compile time.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t... Is> struct seq{};

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq: gen_seq<N-1, N, Is...> {};

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...>{};

namespace math{
    template<typename T> constexpr T pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327;
    template<typename T> constexpr T two_pi = 6.28318530717958647692528676656;
    template<typename T> constexpr T half_pi = pi<T> * 0.5;

    constexpr static double pi_v = pi<double>;
    constexpr static double two_pi_v = two_pi<double>;
    constexpr static double half_pi_v = half_pi<double>;

    template<class T,class dcy = std::decay_t<T>>
    constexpr inline std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value,dcy> inverse(T value){
        return (value == 0) ? 0.0 : 1.0 / value;
    }
    constexpr inline long double factorial(std::intmax_t const& n){
        if(n==0){return 1;}
        long double result = n;
        for(std::intmax_t i=n-1;i>0;--i){
            result *=i;
        }
        return result;
    }
    constexpr inline std::size_t max_factorial(){
        std::size_t i=0;
        long double d=0;
        while ((d= factorial(i))<std::numeric_limits<long double>::max()){++i;}
        return i;
    }

    template<class base,std::size_t N>
    class trig_coeffs {
        using T = typename base::value_type;
        using array_type = std::array<T,N>;

        template<std::size_t ... NS>
        constexpr static inline array_type _coeffs(seq<NS ...>){
            return {{base::coeff(NS) ...}};
        }
    public:
        constexpr static array_type coeffs=_coeffs(gen_seq<N>{});
    };
    template<class base,std::size_t N>
    constexpr typename trig_coeffs<base,N>::array_type trig_coeffs<base,N>::coeffs;


    template<class base,std::size_t N, class dcy = std::decay_t<typename base::value_type>>
    constexpr std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<dcy>::value,dcy>
    _sincos(typename base::value_type x) noexcept{
        using c = trig_coeffs<base,N>;

        if(std::isnan(x) && std::numeric_limits<dcy>::has_quiet_NaN){
            return static_cast<dcy>(std::numeric_limits<dcy>::quiet_NaN());
        }
        else if(std::isinf(x) && std::numeric_limits<dcy>::has_infinity){
            return static_cast<dcy>(std::numeric_limits<dcy>::infinity());
        }
        else{
            dcy result = 0.0;//result accumulator
            //do input range mapping
            dcy _x =base::range_reduce(x);
            //taylor series
            {
                const dcy x_2 = _x*_x; //store x^2
                dcy pow = base::initial_condition(_x);
                for(auto&& cf: c::coeffs){
                    result +=  cf * pow;
                    pow*=x_2;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    namespace detail{
        template<class T>
        struct _sin{
            using value_type = T;
            constexpr static inline T coeff(std::size_t n)noexcept  {
                return (n % 2 ? 1 : -1) * inverse(factorial((2 * n)-1));
            }
            constexpr static inline T range_reduce(T x)noexcept{
                T _x = x;
                _x += math::pi<T>;
                _x -= static_cast<std::size_t>(_x / math::two_pi<T>) * math::two_pi<T>;
                _x -= math::pi<T>;
                return _x;
            }
            constexpr static inline T initial_condition(T x)noexcept{
                return x;
            }
            constexpr static inline std::size_t default_N()noexcept{
                return 16;
            }
        };
    }
    template<class T,std::size_t N = detail::_sin<T>::default_N()>
    constexpr inline std::decay_t<T> sin(T x)noexcept{
        return _sincos<detail::_sin<T>,N>(x);
    }

}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    double phs =0;
    double stp = math::two_pi_v/100.0;
    for(int i = 0;i<100;++i){
        std::cout<<math::sin(phs)<<std::endl;
        phs+=stp;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have posted all of the code needed to compile the example.
[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efc0d54056ddd362)

Comment: for sequences generator, STL has `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`

Comment: For `constexpr T pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327`, `pi` will lose precision whenever `T` is longer than double. At least you should use `L` suffix on the literal, so that all built-in types are supported well enough. Similarly in other such places.

Comment: It's not really constexpr, see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ac2f90cd81bc80e

Comment: @Ruslan: It's constexpr with C++17, I think, with `std::array` being constexpr'ified.

Comment: @einpoklum good to know, but note the title and tags of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

This fails to compile, due to failure to include `<cstdint>`.  I find it easier to spot missing headers if the includes are sorted in a consistent order, such as alphabetically.

---

The function doesn't deliver its promise of compile-time compilation, due to the use of `std::array` which isn't `constexpr` until C++17.  If I declare

```
    static constexpr auto sine_zero = math::sin(0.);
```

I get this compilation failure:

```
133668.cpp:144:48:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘math::sin<double>(0.0)’
133668.cpp:112:42:   in ‘constexpr’ expansion of ‘math::_sincos<detail::_sin<double>, 16>(x)’
133668.cpp:80:17: error: call to non-‘constexpr’ function ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = double; long unsigned int _Nm = 16; const_iterator = const double*]’
   80 |                 for(auto&& cf: c::coeffs){
      |                 ^~~
In file included from 133668.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/13/array:131:7: note: ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::value_type* std::array<_Tp, _Nm>::begin() const [with _Tp = double; long unsigned int _Nm = 16; const_iterator = const double*]’ declared here
  131 |       begin() const noexcept
      |       ^~~~~
```

---

`main()` doesn't use its arguments, so we could use the no-arg form `int main()`.

We can also omit `return 0;` as that's optional in `main()`.

---

Since we have an oracle in the form of `std::sin()`, we can compare our results to what we actually should get.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
auto err_ulp(T a, T b)
{
    std::size_t err = 0;
    while (a != b && err < 1'000'000) {
        a = std::nextafter(a, b);
        ++err;
    }
    return err;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = -50;  i < 50;  ++i) 
        if (i % 50 == 0) { continue; } // CPU limit exceeded
        double d = i * math::two_pi_v/100.0;
        auto val = math::sin(d);
        auto ref = std::sin(d);
        std::cout << "sin(" << 2*i << "π/100)="
                  << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10)
                  << val << " - err = "
                  << err_ulp(val, ref) << " ulp\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Even in this small range, I'm seeing double-digit error values.  If we consider values further from 0, we get very large errors.  For example:

```
sin(1000001π/100)=0.0314107591 - err = 144463 ulp
```

The error is even worse (and execution times are terrible) with `long double` input:

```
sin(1000001π/100)=0.0314107591 - err = 342775 ulp
```

In short, we're getting inaccurate results from summing the Taylor series (likely through adding values largest-first rather than smallest-first).

It's actually worse than that:

```
    std::cout << math::sin(-10.) << '\n';  /* Not A Number */
```

I think the culprit here is `range_reduce` which uses an unsigned type for arithmetic.  If we change that to:

```
            constexpr static inline T range_reduce(T x) noexcept
            {
                return std::fmod(x, math::two_pi<T>);
            }
```

Then we get sensible results for negative inputs, and as a bonus it roughly halves the error in the large positive inputs I tried.  Unfortunately, `std::fmod()` isn't `constexpr` in C++14, but it shows somewhere we could be doing much better.

---

I think `gen_seq` shouldn't be in the global namespace.  It probably shouldn't even exist, as we could simply transform a `std::make_index_sequence`.

---

I don't see any good reason to write `pi` longhand when `two_pi` is available.  Write it as a division by 2, as for `half_pi`.  Remember that division by two is exact in binary floating-point (excepting denormal numbers, which this is not).

---

It's not clear why we always calculate `factorial()` as a `long double`, when the `double` and `float` versions immediately convert to those types after inverting.  In fact, there's no reason not to generate 1/n! directly:

```
    template<typename T>
    constexpr inline auto inverse_factorial(unsigned n) {
        T result = 1;
        while (n) {
            result /= n--;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

(I changed the argument to plain `unsigned`, as that can represent at least 65535, and 65535! is around 10²⁸⁷¹⁸⁹ - far more than any floating-point format I've ever heard of.)

---

In `max_factorial()`, `d` is a write-only variable and can be removed.  I'd re-write to match `inverse_factorial()`:

```
    template<typename T>
    constexpr inline unsigned max_factorial()
    {
        unsigned i = 1;
        for (T x = 1.0;  x /= i;  ++i)
            ;
        return i;
    }
```

It turns out this function isn't even used.  We *could* use it for `default_N()`, but that will result in far too many terms.  We probably only need to go from 1 down to ε; for extra reassurance, we could go down to ε²:

```
    template<typename T>
    constexpr inline unsigned max_factorial()
    {
        constexpr auto limit =
            std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
        unsigned i = 1;
        for (T x = 1.0;  (x /= i) > limit;  ++i)
            ;
        return i;
    }
```

Now that makes a good implementation for `default_N()`.

---

## The good news

It's very rare for a program to have many trigonometric calculations that would benefit from compile-time computation.

## The better news

From C++26 onwards, `std::sin` is declared `constexpr`.  So you can safely use it in the initialisation of your constant objects once your Standard Library is sufficiently updated.  Some platforms support this even when compiling for C++14, so it's something you can test for with a suitable `autoconf` macro, for example.